# Keyboard doesnt work after windows 7 starts

Tags: keyboard

When I start my computer, keyboard lights up, but after the windows 7 starts the keyboard becomes totally inactive and cannot use the keyboard. 
I have tried to use wireless keyboard, wired keyboard and also checked on the keyboard drivers. Its corrupted

Comment: Since you know the keyboard drivers are corrupted, have you tried to reinstall them?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the black USB 2 ports or install the needed drivers for USB3.0 from the site of your MB manufacturer's. The operating system Windows 7 is not compatible with USB 3.0 from the scratch!

Comment: Windows 7 does not have built-in USB 3.0 support but after you install official drivers from manufacturer's site they should work fine.

Comment: Yes, it's true - either need to use USB2 or to install drivers :)